# Flutter navigate keeping previous screen visible at the bottom

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, navigation

I am currently working on a project where the navigation is organized in a next way. When the user navigates from one screen to another, the previous screen remains at the bottom (screenshot below)

Generally, the effect I am trying to achieve is similar to native Android's `fragmentManager.add` functionality, when the Fragment1 overlaps Fragment2, but unfortunately, using the Flutter wasn't able to achieve the same

For navigation, I am using the regular `flutter navigator`

Would appreciate it if someone can help me with this

[image: Navigation image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, but either way, it has to do with the [Route](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route-class.html) object.

The first one is to push a [DialogRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DialogRoute-class.html) instead of a [MaterialPageRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute-class.html). This way, you directly get a transparent route that will allow the content below the route to be displayed.

The second one which needs you to do a bit more work is to extend the [ModalRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute-class.html) object to create your own Route class (you will need to create your animation etc...). So this way is clearly more robust, but if you are new to Flutter, I would recommend that you pick the first one :D.

I hope that helps!

Here is an example of the first option:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Text('TAP ME'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              DialogRoute(
                  builder: (_) => Material(
                    color: Colors.black45,
                    child: Center(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                        child: Text('BACK'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  context: context),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, your input was very helpful. Dialog worked for me, I will customize it manually. Marking question as closed